# how to avoid that powershell select-object displays enum as number?

Tags: powershell

`Get-DnsClientServerAddress` prints:

```
InterfaceAlias               Interface Address ServerAddresses                                                                                                                                                                                       
                             Index     Family                                                                                                                                                                                                        
--------------               --------- ------- ---------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Ethernet0                            3 IPv4    {192.168.0.1}
```

`Get-DnsClientServerAddress | select-object AddressFamily` prints:

```
AddressFamily
-------------
            2
```

question: how can I achieve a output with the string of the enum instead of the number (like this:)

```
AddressFamily
-------------
         IPv4
```

Comment: `Select -expand AddressFamily`

Comment: no :(
`Get-DnsClientServerAddress | select -expand AddressFamily` also prints numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddressFamily display values use the internal enumeration that we can use as well:

```
Get-DnsClientServerAddress |
    Select InterfaceAlias, @{N='AddressFamily'; E={[Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.DnsClientServerAddress.AddressFamily]$_.AddressFamily}}
```

> ```
> InterfaceAlias                                AddressFamily
> --------------                                -------------
> Ethernet                                               IPv4
> Ethernet                                               IPv6
> Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1                            IPv4
> Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1                            IPv6
> isatap.{B9F500B1-943E-4B8C-BCAF-A669F1B0969F}          IPv4
> isatap.{B9F500B1-943E-4B8C-BCAF-A669F1B0969F}          IPv6
> Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface                      IPv4
> Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface                      IPv6
> ```

To quickly get the long enum name, simply type `[addressf` in PS ISE and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> to show the candidates (two in Win10), then select the one with `cmdlet` in its tooltip (second in Win10).

Comment: well I think this solution is cleaner than the previous one, so I will accept this one..thx :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom select expression which changes the address family number value with its corresponding string value. As [@Ansgar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) suggested you can use a lookup table `$af` to switch out these values out.

```
$af = @{'2'='IPv4';'23'='IPv6'}

Get-DnsClientServerAddress | Select InterfaceAlias,InterfaceIndex,@{
    Name="AddressFamily";
    Expression={$af[$_.AddressFamily.ToString()]}
},ServerAddresses
```

If you captured this output into a variable you would be able to select the address family like so `$Variable.AddressFamily` and you would get ether `IPv4` or `IPv6` rather than its number value.

Comment: Since this is basically a lookup operation I'd prefer a hashtable over `-replace`. Something like `$af = @{2='IPv4';23='IPv6'}`, and then `$af[$_.AddressFamily]` in the calculated property.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Good point, I have updated my answer with a working version of this.